# Excel VBA - Select All Columns & Rows After Last Occupied Column & Row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out the code that identifies the last occupied column in the sheet then deletes all columns after that.  I'm also trying to figure out the code that identifies the last occupied row in the sheet then delete all rows after that.

So far I've got the idea that I will need to use `Rows.Count` function but I'm having trouble getting it to select the entire rows after the last occupied row.  Same for columns...  This is what I've come up with so far which only identifies the last occupied row.  Does anyone know how to get it to now select the entire rows after this?  And similarly for the entire columns?  I can't seem to figure out the code to select the last occupied column like I can with rows... Thank you in advance

Rows:
`Sheets("ppCopy").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: If your last occupied column could be in any row, and vice versa for rows, then your best bet is to use Find https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Comment: Also, why do you want to select them?

Comment: @SJR I want to delete them all afterwards.  My files are huge and I found out if I delete all columns and all rows all the way to the end that are blank, my file size shrinks enormously.  Seems like a widespread issue with Excel.

Comment: You might want to try this function http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/lastcell.htm#MakeLastCell

Comment: @SJR that function works perfectly!  I'm looking into combining Ron's code to find lastrow and lastcol to become the activecell in McRitchie's code...do you know off the top of your head if that's possible or if I should look for another way to identify the last used cell?

Comment: @Sjr Figured it out!  Had to do ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn).Select then use that as the activecell in McRitchie's code

Comment: Nice one, I was going to suggest something similar.

Comment: I have extended my answer to add the code to delete All Rows and All Columns after finding the last used row and column. It is also coded on a way that you don't need to do any Select or Activate, meaning you can run it on hidden sheets, inactive sheets, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the code and try to make sense of it and the answer will come to you.

Break down what you already know.

```
Sheets("ppCopy").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Rows.Count = Last Available Row

End(xlUp) = move UP from the last available row (Rows.Count) to the last used row.

How do you get the column then?

```
Sheets("ppCopy").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Columns.Count = Last Available Column

End(xlToLeft) = Move Left from the last available column (Columns.Count) to the last used Column.

Here is how to delete unused Rows and Columns:

```
Sub deleteUnused()
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Integer 'there are a lot of rows compared to columns
    Dim lastLetter As String, firstLetter As String
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    With wk.Sheets("Sheet1")
        'Get last used rows and columns based on valued from Column A and Row 1
        lastRow = .Cells(Excel.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp).Row
        lastColumn = .Cells(1, Excel.Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).Column
        'Delete Rows
        .Rows("" & (lastRow + 1) & ":" & Excel.Rows.Count & "").EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        'Delete columns, tricky because you need the Column Letters instead of the numbers
        lastColumn = lastColumn + 1
        firstLetter = Split(.Cells(, lastColumn).Address, "$")(1)
        lastLetter = Split(.Cells(, Excel.Columns.Count).Address, "$")(1)
        .Columns("" & firstLetter & ":" & lastLetter & "").EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlLeft
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm...I tried to do Cells(Rows.Count + 1, 1).End(xlDown).Row thinking it will identify last row then select the next row and select all down from that but it didn't seem to work.  Is that an incorrect way to make it select the next row after last occupied row?

Comment: You add the +1 after you get the last row. not while you are getting it.

lastRow = Sheets("ppCopy").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Then lastRow = lastRow + 1

Comment: Thank you Ricardo for your code.  I will test it out tomorrow when I get in...learned a lot so far from your post though!

Answer (score 0):

J Doe 
Here is a code that will search for the value in any cell on any column and then select and delete all rows after that and do the same for the columns. No a very technic or something but will do the work and also give you some ideas. It will also include formulas that display empty cells.

Hope this help.

Sub DeleteRowAndColumns()

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ppCopy")
    'find any cell no empty in a row in any row
    .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Select
    'select all the rows
    .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete ' clear all the rows
    'find the last value in any column
    .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Select
    'select columns
    .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Delete 'clear columns
End With
```

End Sub